# Move UITableViewCell while keyboard appear in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using UITableViewController and in that i have some cells with textfields and in last cell i have UITextView.

I want to move the position of last cell which contain textview on keyboard appear but i am not able to do this.
Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: Have you tried TPKeyboardAvoiding?

Comment: Actually i am new in ios and swift so can you tell me what is TPKeyboardAvoiding and where to apply it?

Comment: Scroll down the answers of the duplicate to find solutions in Swift.

Answer (score 1):

Try [TPKeyboardAvoiding](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding).

For use with `UITableViewController` classes, drop TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView.m and `TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView.h` into your project, and make your `UITableView` a `TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView` in the xib. If you're not using a xib with your controller, I know of no easy way to make its UITableView a custom class: The path of least resistance is to create a xib for it.

Hope this helps.